# Emitting IL in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, reflection.emit

I'm trying to create classes dynamically to import XAML binding. It's working well in WPF, but not in Windows Phone 8. Apparently, Windows Phone 8 does not support binding to a `dynamic` data context (it just doesn't try to invoke any of the dynamic methods and properties).

So I thought I'd go the longer route, and emit classes dynamically. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any way to emit IL in Windows Phone 8. The `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace exists, but contains no emitter helper classe. `System.AppDomain` doesn't exist at all, so I can't create a new assembly to place my newly generated classes in.

I noticed `DynamicMethod` is supported, but I need to generate entire classes, not just an anonymous method here and there. Is IL emitting completely forbidden in Windows Phone 8?

Comment: Check [rule 3.9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx)

Comment: Hmmmm. I'm not going to violate the rule - There's no dynamically downloaded code, and the dynamic behavior doesn't interact with the Windows runtime. However, if Microsoft decided to enforce the rule by killing the ability to generate IL on the fly - I'm out of luck.

Comment: @HansPassant that's for Windows 8, not Windows Phone 8.

Comment: That doesn't make any difference, these are store certification requirements.

Answer (score 2):

> Is IL emitting completely forbidden in Windows Phone 8?

Only almost. But a binding doesn't need to be dynamic in the first place. Bindings attempt to access a property of a object without knowing it's type, so even if you bound a `System.Object` as DataContext, you could still have `{Binding SomeProperty}` in your XAML.

Comment: Indeed, but I'm trying to replace your view model with an augmented one that fires PropertyChanged and CollectionChanged events automatically. For this I need to somehow create a class that mimics your view model.

Comment: @zmbq You still don't need dynamics for that, at all.

Comment: How can I dynamically create SomeProperty without doing anything dynamic?

Comment: You don't have to create anything dynamically. Read my answer again.

Comment: It's not what you meant by your answer, but I think you just gave me an idea. Brilliant!